# How to install Python 2.7 in Windows?

Tags: python-2.7

I can't find a link to download Python 2.7 onto Windows 10, does anyone know where I can download it? By the way not any 2.7.13 etc just 2.7.

All I can find are 2.7.13 etc, is it possible?

Comment: `2.7.13` *is* Python `2.7`. Python `2.7` is a branch, which started with `2.7.0`. `2.7.13` still is in that branch, and contains bugfixes for `2.7.0`. As far as I know, there's no reason to use `2.7.0` today. From the `2.7.0` [doc](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) : "Note: A bugfix release, 2.7.13, is currently available. Its use is recommended."

Comment: @EricDuminil no I need 2.7 for a project as .13 works differently

Comment: How does it work differently?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen code that works on 2.7 doesn't on .13

Comment: If for some reason you really want to use `2.7.0`, feel free to use the link in my first comment.

Comment: 2.7.13 **is** 2.7 !! The *13* is the minor revision and will not make any difference.

Comment: Aren't you confusing Python3/Python2.7 with Python2.7.13/Python2.7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can Download [python2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/) with respect to your 32/64-bit processor and install it.

or else follow this [link.](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/setting-up-your-windows-10-system-for-python-development-pydev-eclipse-python/). It shows you all steps with screenshots